# Button set Background to Transparent Color

Tags: android, button, transparent

How can I set the Background for a button to a transparent Color, like transparent Blue for eg, instead of a solid blue?

When I use `button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE)` it sets it to a solid blue.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [Color.argb()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#argb%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). It takes four `int` parameters, each ranging from 0 to 255.

Let's say you want a blue button with 50% alpha:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(125, 0, 0, 255));
```