# disable button with custom background android

Tags: android, button, transparent

When I have an android button and set it as disabled then the button seems as "transparent".

I have a button with custom background for the pressed and focused state. I want to disable it from code.  When I try `button.setEnabled(false);` I disable the button but it keeps the same custom background. Any idea how to disable my custom button and changes the background as transparent too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244022/andrioid-button-set-background-to-transparent-color

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe you could use `android:state_enabled` and set that to appropriate transparent drawable in your selector for this button?

Answer (score 42):

you should create you custom selector like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
    android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_red" />
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_orange" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_orange" />
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_black" />
</selector>
```

Comment: For that selector, create a new XML file in the `res/drawable/ directory`