# Call requires API level 11 (current min is 8): android.widget.EditText#setAlpha

Tags: android

I want to make my `EditText Opacity to 1` which will ensure that it looks like disabled. But since my API level is set to 8, i am not able to apply this method.

Is there anyway we can disable the `EditText and Grey it out`, so that i looks disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `setEnabled(false)` and then apply this kind of style on the button (in the layout xml file):

```
<item android:state_enabled="false" >
<shape>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="#007900"
                android:startColor="#009A77"
                android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#F1FAFE" />
            <corners
                android:radius="5dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Customise the values with colors and effects you want.

Edit:
You will find everything you want to learn how to apply a style on any UI element here: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/08/creating-a-custom-android-button-with-a-resizable-skin/
The example is about buttons but it is the exact same method for any other view.

Comment: Should this xml be under style tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`editText.setEnabled(false);`

Comment: I have already done it, but it does not look disabled for me.

Comment: Are you customising the background? Make sure your background drawable supports the disabled state. More info here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790454/disable-button-with-custom-background-android) it's about buttons but applies to EditText

Comment: <style name="InputTitle" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#A000</item>
    </style>

Comment: I am using the above style for my edit text, is it making some different.

Comment: Try changing the style to inherit from EditText - `parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText"` and see if that helps