# Android Studio - round button inside square

Tags: android

I want to make a round button in Android Studio. I have created a separate xml that I saved in drawable called round_button.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#cccccc"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

Then I used it in my button function.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="ME"
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="119dp"

        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
```

The problem is that my round button seems to be inside a square shape. How can I get rid of it? Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Add a selector as background and in that selector link to your shape http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790454/disable-button-with-custom-background-android

Comment: tried ImageButton ? or use ImageView and make it clickable..

Comment: This is a problem with the visual editor. It does not exist in the actual application, so no need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ImageButton` that has the `src` attribute. Use that to set the drawable, and put the background to null.

```
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/round_button"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="ME"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Button`, you could define corners 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#corners-element 

 for rectangle, for example:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#002244" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>
```